# question about Ubuntu for Smart Phones

Tags: samsung

I have the Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini, if i use Ubuntu on my phone, will I lose features such as SBeam? and will it be compatible with US Cellular Network?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the wiki for the latest touch FAQ [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ)